# getting libstruct to work in matlab for dll pointer argument

Tags: matlab, dll, loadlibrary

I'm trying to call a dll function in matlab. I have a C++ struct as shown in sixense.h:

```
typedef struct _sixenseControllerData {
  float pos[3];
  float rot_mat[3][3];
  float joystick_x;
  float joystick_y;
  float trigger;
  ...
} sixenseControllerData;
```

and functions I could call:

```
SIXENSE_EXPORT int sixenseInit( void );
SIXENSE_EXPORT int sixenseGetAllNewestData( sixenseAllControllerData * );
```

I can easily get this to work with `calllib('sixense','sixenseInit')` since there is no input, but for the function sixenseGetAllNewestData I need to have a struct pointer. I realize that libstruct is what I need to use. However, I don't seem to be doing it right.

So I tried libstruct like so:

```
libstruct('sixenseControllerData')
```

and I get the error:

```
??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or variable 'lib.sixenseControllerData'.

Error in ==> libstruct at 15
    ptr=feval(['lib.' structtype]);
```

EDIT: here is my current unedited proto file:
http://pastebin.com/PemmmMqF

the full header file is available here:
https://github.com/rll/sixense/blob/master/include/sixense.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C structures, [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) generates types named: `s_{NAME}` where `{NAME}` is the name of the structure. In your case we create a [pointer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libstruct.html) as:

```
s = libstruct('s_sixenseControllerData');
```

We can see this fact by instructing MATLAB to generate a [prototype file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/prototype-files.html):

```
>> loadlibrary('sixense', 'sixense.h', 'proto','sixense_proto')
```

A prototype file is a file of MATLAB commands which we can modify and use in place of a header file. In this case, the file will contain something like:

#### sixense_proto.m

```
...
structs.s_sixenseControllerData.members = struct('pos', 'single#3', 'rot_mat', 'single#9', 'joystick_x', 'single', 'joystick_y', 'single', 'trigger', 'single', 'buttons', 'uint32', 'sequence_number', 'uint8', 'rot_quat', 'single#4', 'firmware_revision', 'uint16', 'hardware_revision', 'uint16', 'packet_type', 'uint16', 'magnetic_frequency', 'uint16', 'enabled', 'int32', 'controller_index', 'int32', 'is_docked', 'uint8', 'which_hand', 'uint8', 'hemi_tracking_enabled', 'uint8');
structs.s_sixenseAllControllerData.members = struct('controllers', 's_sixenseControllerData#4');
....
```

Unfortunately, a [limitation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-shared-library-support.html#btfip0t-9) of `loadlibrary` is that it does not support nested structure very well, especially if a structure contains a pointer to another structure (or an array in this case):

> Nested structures or structures containing a pointer to a structure are
>   not supported. However, MATLAB can access an array of
>   structures created in an external library.

So you will not be able to directly create the `sixenseAllControllerData` structure on the MATLAB side, which is defined in the C header file as:

```
typedef struct _sixenseAllControllerData {
    sixenseControllerData controllers[4];
} sixenseAllControllerData;
```

According to the following [discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280224), one workaround is to "unroll"/"flatten" the array into separate variables. You can either do this in a copy of the header file, or making the changes in the generated prototype file (which I think is the preferred way). You can do this without having to recompile the shared library.

In your case, change the nested structure in the generated `sixense_proto.m` file into:

```
structs.s_sixenseAllControllerData.members = struct(...
    'controllers1', 's_sixenseControllerData', ...
    'controllers2', 's_sixenseControllerData', ...
    'controllers3', 's_sixenseControllerData', ...
    'controllers4', 's_sixenseControllerData');
```

[Now](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-AEDTBT/?product=ML&solution=1-AEDTBT) we can create a pointer to this structure, and call the C method:

```
s = libstruct('s_sixenseAllControllerData');
s.controllers1 = libstruct('s_sixenseControllerData');
s.controllers2 = libstruct('s_sixenseControllerData');
s.controllers3 = libstruct('s_sixenseControllerData');
s.controllers4 = libstruct('s_sixenseControllerData');

out = calllib('sixense', 'sixenseGetAllNewestData', s);
get(s)
```

A completely different solution is to write a [MEX-function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html) to interface with the library. It is just like any other C/C++ code, only using `mxArray` and the MX-API to interface with MATLAB...

---

## Example:

To test the above, I created a simple DLL with similar structures, and implemented the above solution. Here is the code if someone wants to test it:

#### helper.h

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H

#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef EXPORT_FCNS
#define EXPORTED_FUNCTION __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTED_FUNCTION __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define EXPORTED_FUNCTION
#endif

#endif
```

#### mylib.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H
#include "helper.h"

typedef struct _mystruct {
    int pos[3];
    double value;
} mystruct;

typedef struct _mystruct2 {
    mystruct arr[2];
    int num;
} mystruct2;

EXPORTED_FUNCTION void myfunc(mystruct *);
EXPORTED_FUNCTION void myfunc2(mystruct2 *);

#endif
```

#### mylib.c

```
#define EXPORT_FCNS
#include "helper.h"
#include "mylib.h"

void myfunc(mystruct *s)
{
    s->pos[0] = 10;
    s->pos[1] = 20;
    s->pos[2] = 30;
    s->value = 4.0;
}

void myfunc2(mystruct2 *s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        myfunc(&(s->arr[i]));
    }
    s->num = 99;
}
```

After compiling the above into a DLL, we generate the initial prototype file:

```
loadlibrary('./mylib.dll', './mylib.h', 'mfilename','mylib_proto')
unloadlibrary mylib
```

I edit the prototype file as described before:

```
function [methodinfo,structs,enuminfo,ThunkLibName] = mylib_proto()
    MfilePath = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
    ThunkLibName = fullfile(MfilePath,'mylib_thunk_pcwin64');

    enuminfo = [];

    structs = [];
    structs.s_mystruct.members = struct('pos','int32#3', 'value','double');
    structs.s_mystruct2.members = struct('arr1','s_mystruct', ...
        'arr2','s_mystruct', 'num','int32');

    ival = {cell(1,0)};
    methodinfo = struct('name',ival, 'calltype',ival, 'LHS',ival, ...
        'RHS',ival, 'alias',ival, 'thunkname',ival);

    methodinfo.thunkname{1} = 'voidvoidPtrThunk';
    methodinfo.name{1} = 'myfunc';
    methodinfo.calltype{1} = 'Thunk';
    methodinfo.LHS{1} = [];
    methodinfo.RHS{1} = {'s_mystructPtr'};

    methodinfo.thunkname{2} = 'voidvoidPtrThunk';
    methodinfo.name{2} = 'myfunc2';
    methodinfo.calltype{2} = 'Thunk';
    methodinfo.LHS{2} = [];
    methodinfo.RHS{2} = {'s_mystruct2Ptr'};
end
```

Now we can finally invoke functions exposed by the DLL:

```
%// load library using proto file
loadlibrary('./mylib.dll', @mylib_proto)

%// call first function with pointer to struct
s = struct('pos',[0,0,0], 'value',0);
ss = libstruct('s_mystruct',s);
calllib('mylib', 'myfunc', ss)
get(ss)

%// call second function with pointer to struct containing array of struct
xx = libstruct('s_mystruct2');
xx.arr1 = libstruct('s_mystruct');
xx.arr2 = libstruct('s_mystruct');
calllib('mylib', 'myfunc2', xx)
get(xx)

%// clear references and unload library
clear ss xx
unloadlibrary mylib
```

Comment: wow thanks Amro! Very detailed answer! I will go through all this and get back to you.

Comment: I don't have nested structs in my problem, but I think the issue for mine is that I have a 3x3 matrix. The proto seems to think that the type is "single#", everything else is either just a single or like "single#3".  How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @mugetsu: you do have nested structures, the function `sixenseGetAllNewestData` takes a pointer to `sixenseAllControllerData` which includes an array of `sixenseControllerData`. As for the 3x3 matrix `rot_mat`, in my case MATLAB correctly generates a proto file with `single#9` type for it (as you can see in my answer above). What platform are you on, MATLAB version, and what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 matlab 2007a. I'm using visual studio c++ express 2010.

Comment: thank you! after reading through a couple times, I finally got things working!