# Loading an Visual Studio DLL into Matlab

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, dll

I have a 64-bit DLL compiled from Visual Studio 2010 coded like this example: [visual studio Dll and Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413118/visual-studio-dll-and-matlab)

When I call `loadlibrary` in Matlab (64-bit), I get the following error message:

```
Error using loadlibrary (line 254)
A 'Selected' compiler was not found.  You may need to run mex
-setup.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you must specify which compiler was used to generate your library. Use `mex -setup` to do this.

I think Matlab needs to know which compiler was used to generate the library because the ABI is compiler-dependent for C++... Although I see in the other answer that they use `extern "C"` to export the functions, which should make them compliant with the C ABI, which is more or less standard on x86_64 Windows, so I'm not quite sure about this...